# file input and output, loops creating new line

Tags: c, encryption, file-io

i am having trouble with my code. i have for loops that decrypt/encrypt a phrase based on a key the user enters. the program is run from the command line by doing:

```
./program [-d] [-e] key sourcefile destinationfile
```

The [-d] and [-e] means decrypt or encrypt, the user can only specify one option. the program takes the phrase of text from the sourcefile, manipulates it, and then writes the new phrase to a new file. however, i noticed for some reason my for loops split up the phrase and screw up the sequence in the new file depending on the key. see the results i get below when i encrypt:

```
key    source                      dest
2      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     Tsig24680BDFetn13579ACE      correct
3      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     Ttg369BEei1470CFsn258AD      correct
4      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     Ti260Den37AEsg47BFt159C      correct
5      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     Tn49Deg50Es16AFt27B          incorrect
                                   i38C
6      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     Tg6Be17Cs28Dt39Ei40Fn5A      correct
7      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     T18Ee29Fs30                  incorrect
                                   t4Ai5Bn6Cg7D
8      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     T20e3As4Bt5Ci6Dn7Eg8F19       correct
9      Testing1234567890ABCDEF     T3be4Cs5Dt6Ei7Fn8
                                   g9102A                       incorrect
10     Testing1234567890ABCDEF     T4De5Es6Ft7
                                   i8n9g01A2B3C                 incorrect
```

notice how using 5, 7, 9, and 10 split up the phrase on two lines? thats not supposed to happen, i dont even have a newline character in the loops. i cant figure out whats causing this.

my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int main ( int argc, char* argv[ ] ) {
        FILE* sourcefile;
        FILE* destfile;
        int i, j, filesize, key;
        int pos = 0;
        char phrase[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
        char* newPhrase;

        /* if user types -d or -e continue */
        if ( ( argc == 5 && ( strcmp ( argv[ 1 ], "-d") == 0 ) ) || ( argc == 5 && ( strcmp ( argv[ 1 ], "-d") == 0 ) ) ) {

                /* exit if key is not an int */
                key = atoi ( argv[ 2 ] );
                if ( key < 1 ) {
                        perror ( "Error: key is not a valid int" );
                        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                /* open source & destination files */
                sourcefile = fopen ( argv[ 3 ], "r" );
                /* display error message if source file does not exist */
                if ( sourcefile == NULL ) {
                        perror ( "" );
                        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                destfile = fopen ( argv[ 4 ], "w" );

                /* extract the text in the source file */
                fgets ( phrase, BUFFER_SIZE, sourcefile );
                fseek ( sourcefile, 0, SEEK_END );
                filesize = ftell ( sourcefile );

                /* allocate memory for new string that will go in destination file */
                newPhrase = ( char* ) malloc ( filesize );

                /* decrypt */
                if ( strcmp ( argv[ 1 ], "-d" ) == 0 ) {
                        for (i = 0; i < key; i++) {
                                for (j = i; j < strlen( phrase ); j += key)
                                        newPhrase[ j ] = phrase[ pos++ ];
                        }
                }
                /* encrypt */
                else {
                        for (i = 0; i < key; i++) {
                                for (j = i; j < strlen( phrase ); j += key)
                                        newPhrase[ pos++ ] = phrase[ j ];
                        }
                }
                /* write new phrase to file, close files */
                fputs( newPhrase, destfile );
                fclose ( sourcefile );
                fclose ( destfile );
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger! Ask, if you have a specific question. "Here's my code, find the bug for me" is not quite a good question.

Comment: Offtopic: you're not freeing `newPhrase`

Comment: You're not zero'ing out `newPhrase`, try `newPhrase[pos++] = '\0'` before the `fputs` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your program is working fine.

what is confusing you is that the trailing newline at the end of the first line in the input file is being included in the phrase.

because the phrase, including trailing newline, is 24 characters, and you are using an "encryption" that selects "nth" characters, things work fine when you have an "n" that divides 24 because the trailing newline ends up at the end of the phase.  so 2, 3, 4, 6 and 8 all work ok (it's amusing that you picked a phase that has a length with so many divisors...)

but for other values of "n" the trailing newline, that terminates the input string, ends up in the middle of the encrypted string.  once you see that, the "incorrect" output is correct.

[edit:] this has been updated; originally i thought it was the 0 that terminates strings in C that was causing problems.  that original answer was wrong, sorry.

if you want to "fix" this, you can just shorten the string after reading it:

```
while (strlen(phrase) && phrase[strlen(phrase)-1] == '\n') phrase[strlen(phrase)-1] = '\0'
```

ps looking at your history you have marked no answers as correct.  normally, if someone posts a correct answer, you click the "tick" mark above and to the left of the answer and then the answerer (me) gets internet points, which give meaning to our otherwise sad lives.

Comment: On your PS: member for a month, needs to read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and earn the 'Informed' badge ...

Comment: very good, thank you very much for the help & explanation. Your code fixed my issue.